# Как можно сравнить аргумент функции int с индексом

Tags: c++

как мне сравнивать не string с int'ом а индекс массива с int'ом?

```
int bin_search(std::string list[], int val) {
    
    int low = 0;
    int high =  (sizeof(list)/ sizeof(*list)) - 1;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        
        if (val == list[mid]) {
            std::cout << "Your item this pos:\t" << mid << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (val == list[mid])
        {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return 1;
```

Comment: `val==mid`? Только какой смысл от этого?

Comment: @maestro спасибо нашёл ошибку

Comment: `int high =  (sizeof(list)/ sizeof(*list)) - 1;` так можно делать только с массивами, но не с классами. Ищите готовый метод получения длины строки в классе `std::string`.

Comment: Пора делать новый стандартный вопрос с ответом — как **не** надо определять размер массива...

    `int high =  (sizeof(list)/ sizeof(*list));`

В *функцию* `list` передается как указатель, и `high` у вас — размер указателя, деленный нацело на размер `string`...

Comment: Да, скобочки [] я не заметил. Но это не отменяет сказанное: данная операция допустима только для массивов, размер которых известен на этапе компиляции. Во всех остальных случаях операция выполнится, но не так, как вы ожидаете.